# Zombie NSString when called from another object

Tags: ios, oop, exc-bad-access, objective-c++, nszombie

I can pass basic data between classes, but when I try to pass a `NSString*` from my `UIApplicationDelegate` I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` / `NSZombie`.

Is there something special I have to do to return an `NSObject`? Does this have to do with threading? (I thought the `atomic` setting on the property would take care of that?)

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  NSString * currentNoteName;
}
@property (atomic, assign) NSString *currentNoteName;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)timerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    currentNoteName = [NSString stringWithCString:(tone->freq).c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// This works:
    NSLog(@"Current Note Name in timerCallback: %@", currentNoteName);
```

OtherObject.m:

```
// Returns a Zombie object & EXC_BAD_ACCESS:
NSString *currentNoteName = [appDelegate currentNoteName];
```

Comment: are you executing on iOS 5 with ARC enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not using ARC, you must using retain property:

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSString *currentNoteName;
```

and assign a value for it, using setter:

```
self.currentNoteName = [NSString stringWithCString: ...];
```

and don't forget to release instance of this ivar in your `dealloc` implementation of `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void) dealloc {
  [currentNoteName release], currentNoteName = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. Thanks. I was looking for something complicated when it was actually simple...

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning a value and autoreleasing the NSString instance. Use retain instead.

Answer (score 0):

The probleis is "assign", because the string from " [NSString stringWithCString" is auto-released.
Maybe u can change it to "copy" or "retain". (i think copy is better).